# Selenium : Facing Problem in retrieving data from Table where visible and hidden items share common tags

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Helo All,
I am facing issue in retrieving data from Table where visible and hidden items share common tags. Please guide me through .. 
<>

```
HTML Code for Hidden items:

<tr class="Bio Medical" style="display:none">
<td>30.</td>
<td>40 NB Multiport Valve</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-inventory-quantity-169128">
<input id="edit-inventory-quantity-169128" class="form-text" type="text" maxlength="128" size="10" value="" name="inventory_quantity_169128"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

Code for items which are visible:

<tr class="Consumable" style="">
<td>2</td>
<td>4-Prong Disposable Set</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-inventory-quantity-1053441">
<input id="edit-inventory-quantity-1053441" class="form-text" type="text" maxlength="128" size="10" value="" name="inventory_quantity_1053441"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here I need to get name of the item which is lying in 2nd column and QTY which is lying in 3rd column for the element which is visible

Difficulties with my trials: 
1) Class name for tr tag changes based on the input criteria

Thanks in Advance

karunakar Reddy

Comment: What programming language are you using? What is your programming skill level? Task seems like simple enough loop.